# typelib: /usr/lib/libGL.so.1: file too short after installing AMD drivers

Tags: ati, 14.04, hybrid-graphics

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 in a Samsung laptop.

I've installed this morning AMD propietary drivers as explained here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evqpassbyqA

My AMD card for the first time performed as never before in games.

The problem is after switching back to Intel's card some applications are not working anymore because when I try to run them I get errors like this one `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1: file too short`  but with different files.

If I try to run the Catalyst Center I get this :amdcccle:13579):

```
Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
```

I've tried different things that are recommended in different threads but I can't find a solution.

I've tried this:

```
     sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libgsoap4 libvncserver0 linux-image-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6 450 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 amd64 2.4.0-1ubuntu2 [6 450 kB]
Fetched 6 450 kB in 4s (1 345 kB/s)             
(Reading database ... 205548 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwebkitgtk-3.0-0_2.4.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 (2.4.0-1ubuntu2) over (2.4.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 (2.4.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /usr/lib/libGL.so is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2 is empty, not checked.
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 with AMD Drivers:

```
$ sudo ldconfig |grep libOpenCL.so.1
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

So I checked it:

```
$ locate libOpenCL.so.1| xargs du -sh    
28K /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1    
28K /usr/lib/fglrx/libOpenCL.so.1    
32K /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1    
36K /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0    
0   /usr/lib/pxpress/lib/libOpenCL.so.1    
0   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1    
36K /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0    
32K /usr/lib32/fglrx/libOpenCL.so.1     
0   /usr/lib32/pxpress/lib/libOpenCL.so.1
```

and made symlink with the same size:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1.bak    
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/fglrx/libOpenCL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1    
sudo ldconfig
```

So I don't receive this error any more